# ZeroMQ + ReactPHP: Multiple producers (push) and multiple consumers (pull)

Tags: php, message-queue, zeromq, reactphp

I'm using [reactphp/zmq](https://github.com/reactphp/zmq).

How can I have multiple push workers within multiple pull workers, is that possible?

A only can have multi pull and single push, as in README's example:

```php
$push->connect()
$pull->bind()
```

Or single pull and multi pushes:

```php
$push->bind()
$pull->connect()
```

When I try to set both as `connect` **the pulls doesn't receive the messages**.

Otherwise, trying to start more than one process with `bind` it throws:

```
ZMQSocketException: Failed to bind the ZMQ: Address in use
```

---

Should I have a middleware?

```
(5555)                      (5556)
push -|  (5555) > (5556)   |- pull
push -|-> pull  &  push <- |- pull
push -|   bind  /  bind    |- pull
connect                    connect
```

Comment: What are you solving with that proposed architecture? Why would you need to have multiple pushers? You can't have multiple pushers and then have random amount of workers that pull. You need to have a single endpoint where all workers PUSH and a single endpoint where all workers PULL from. Luckily, ZeroMQ supports `TIPC` protocol that makes this easy, but it's probably wiser that you explain *what* exactly you're trying to do so we can suggest optimal architecture.

Comment: I'm building a email validation tool where when a new list is added, it starts a new pusher that adds its emails to the queue while multiple pullers will be listening to that queue to validating them.

Comment: You have the fan-out (pusher, the one that **gives** the task) and you have the worker, the one that **performs** the task. You **don't have the queue**. ZeroMQ is transport layer, not queue (it uses queue internally though). What you need is a service in the middle that acts as a queue - it receives and sends tasks. Your pusher pushes to queue, your pull-er pulls from the queue. That service would use `pull` to receive the task and `push` to hand it out to workers. You use `push` to give it tasks and `pull` to take tasks from it.

Comment: Ok, so in the end this middleware thing I'm thinking is the "queue", right? You think it is safe to rely on ZeroMQ to do this queuing thing? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! Thank you very much [@Mjh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1133682/mjh) for clarifying things.

Turns out that I do need something in the middle that should be a message queue broker and ZMQ does have something for that. Internally calling `zmq_proxy` starts a `rrbroker` loop, unfortunately theses guys aren't abstracted at reactphp/zmq, but they are at ext-php through `ZMQDevice`.

Source: http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter2#ZeroMQ-s-Built-In-Proxy-Function

Answer (score 0):

```
(5555)                      (5556)
push -|  (5555) > (5556)   |- pull
push -|-> pull  &  push <- |- pull
push -|   bind  /  bind    |- pull
connect                    connect
```

This is very similar to ZMQPoll idea. Bad you do not required use reactphp/zmq

You can run process with ZMQPoll. This process can be bound on 5555 and 5556. And other process can push and pull messages.

[my example how it can be work](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/gollariel/nAjnk)

[more examples on official ZMQ site](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:all)

[PHP example poller from official site](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:mspoller)

**UPD:** If you want other solution, [look at ZMQProxy](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/gollariel/8Axx4)

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think that Poll solves the oposite problem.
I need something like: N-1-N and Poll does: 1-N-1, its a middleware that receives from multiple endpoints, but these endpoints should be bound to a unique address, then I will need to `bind` each push and each pull to a single port. I want to `connect` all needed pushers in one port and all needed pullers in one port too.

Comment: ZMQPoll solved your problem. You connect to 5555 port all needed pushers, and you connect to 5556 all needed pullers.
But if you want other solution, look at proxy https://bitbucket.org/snippets/gollariel/8Axx4